# How to convert inline css from tags of Iframe to classes in a text box?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, inline

I have a page with an Iframe and Textbox in it. The page that loads in the Iframe has inline css in its tags and I want to remove them and show them in the textbox as normal class css which usually comes between style tag

For example, this is what I have in Iframe:

```
    <div class="main-div" style="height:100vh; background-color:red;"></div>
```

expected output in textbox

```
    .main-div{
        height: 100vh;
        background-color:red;
     }
```

It should return the similar output for all the divs.

Please suggest solution based on CSS, JS and Jquery

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Yes, some of the stackoverflow examples, but none of them worked. The main idea is to get the three text boxes
1). Textbox 1: That has a content which in between the <body></body> tag of iframe
2). Textbox 2: To get the css of iframe which is converted from inline css to the class mentioned
3). Textbox 3: To get the the data of script tag.
And if something is changed in the Iframe, it should reflect in these three textboxes.